# In AWS Lambda, when running GetObjectCommand with S3Client, a zip file with macos .DS_Store file always gives error: Z_BUF_ERROR

Tags: node.js, macos, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zip

I have this code that extract a zip file in S3 bucket into local file system, using nodejs stream to avoid downloading the entire zip file first, thus saving memory:

```
const streamUnzipFromS3ToLocal = async (
  objectBucket: string,
  objectKey: string,
  extractDir: string,
) => {
  logger.info(`Start to stream unzip ${objectBucket}:${objectKey} to local.`);
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  try {
    const data = await S3.getFile(objectBucket, objectKey); // data.Body is a readable stream;
    data.Body.on('error', (error) => {
      logger.error(`Error while reading the stream: ${error}`);
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    });
    await pipeline(data.Body, unzipper.Extract({ path: extractDir }));
    logger.info(`${objectKey} is decompressed to ${extractDir}`);
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Failed to stream unzip file ${objectKey}: ${error}`);
    console.log(error);
    throw error
  }
  var end = new Date().getTime();
  var time = (end - start) / 1000;
  logger.info(`Finished stream-unzipping ${objectKey} to local. execution time: ${time} sec;`);
  return time;
};
```

and `S3.getFile` is as follows:

```
export const getFile = async (bucket_name, object_key) => {
  let res;
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket_name,
    Key: object_key,
  };

  try {
    const x = new GetObjectCommand(params);
    const data = await s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand(params));
    res = data;
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(`Failed when s3Controller getFile: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
    throw err;
  }

  return res;
};
```

I am getting this error when using the above code to stream unzip a zip file in S3 bucket:

```
2023-05-02T07:50:26.583Z  ee92598e-78ce-4988-a92a-9f70bd3d65c7  ERROR Failed to stream unzip file issues/src-HosE/dst-HosX/2023-05-02-16-49/76dd8c954aff6835/raw/0808_2_with_DS_Store_file.zip: {
    "errno": -5,
    "code": "Z_BUF_ERROR"
}


2023-05-02T07:50:26.583Z  ee92598e-78ce-4988-a92a-9f70bd3d65c7  ERROR Failed to process attachment 0808_2_with_DS_Store_file.zip of issue 716: Error: unexpected end of file

2023-05-02T07:50:26.586Z  ee92598e-78ce-4988-a92a-9f70bd3d65c7  ERROR Error while reading the stream: {
    "code": "ECONNRESET"
}
```

As you can tell from the file name: `issues/src-HosE/dst-HosX/2023-05-02-16-49/76dd8c954aff6835/raw/0808_2_with_DS_Store_file.zip`, this is a zip file created in MacBook and it contains the signature file `.DS_Store` in macos.

I have made two files:

1. 0808_2_with_DS_Store_file.zip
2. 0808_2.zip

Everything is identical in the two, except that one contains the `.DS_Store` file.

And I have tested them in two environments:

1. Running the code with AWS Lambda Function;
2. Running the nodejs code in EC2 instance;

What I observed is this:

- In EC2 instance, the code can process both files with no problem.
- In AWS Lambda, the code can only process `0808_2.zip` successfully, and when running with `0808_2_with_DS_Store_file.zip`, it always gives the error above.